# Python Docxtpl - не заполняются таблицы

Tags: python, docxtpl

Вот шаблон
[image: Шаблон]
Вот код для вставки:

```
"percent_45Rows":[
            {'subject': 'lishlgk', 'year': 'sjdflk', 'all_count': '60', 'stud_5': '20', 'stud_4': '20', 'percent': '60%'}
],
```

После вызова функции `render` лишь названия колонок и ничего более
Где я мог ошибиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на то, что таблица не заполнялась оказался неожиданным, лично для меня
Если вы в своей переменной `context` загружаете и текстовые, и табличные данные, а также изображения, то их нужно правильно расположить их в словаре
Так чтобы загрузка изображений была в самом конце словаря
Лично мне помогло, возможно может и вам